# Stuck on showing a functional is not a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ show that the following
$$N[u]=[|u_1|^{\frac{1}{2}}+|u_2|^{\frac{1}{2}}+...+|u_n|^{\frac{1}{2}}]^2 $$
is not a norm for the space when $n>1$.

I've started with the case where $n=2$, and have shown some of the norm properties are true, leading me to believe this falls apart as a norm about the triangle inequality property. Here's where I've gotten to with just the algebra:

$$N[x+y] = [|x_1 + y_1|^{\frac{1}{2}} + |x_2 + y_2|^{\frac{1}{2}}]^2 \leq [|x_1|^\frac{1}{2} +|x_2|^\frac{1}{2} ]^{2} + [|y_1|^\frac{1}{2} +|y_2|^\frac{1}{2} ]^{2}  $$
$$|x_1+y_1|+2\sqrt{|x_1+y_1||x_2+y_2|}+|x_2+y_2| \leq |x_1|+|y_1| +2\sqrt{|x_1||x_2|} +2\sqrt{|y_1||y_2|}+|x_2|+|y_2|$$

I'm just a little unsure of where to go from here. I feel like I am close, but am maybe missing some forgotten trick of algebra?

Comment: You want to show this inequality fails. Try picking some simple values for $x_i$ and $y_i$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$,

$$N[x]=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{\lvert{x_j}\rvert}\right)^2.$$

Now let $n\geq 2$, and consider $x=(1,\dots,1),y=(1,0,\dots,0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then

\begin{align*}
N[x+y]
&=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{\lvert{x_j+y_j}\rvert}\right)^2 \\
&=(\sqrt{2}+n-1)^2 \\
&=n^2+2n(\sqrt{2}-1)+(\sqrt{2}-1)^2
\end{align*}

and

$$N[x]+N[y]=n^2+1.$$

Here it's easy to show, using your favorite method, that

$$N[x+y]>N[x]+N[y]$$

for our choices of $x$ and $y$ whenever $n\geq 2$, and so the triangle inequality fails.